# A Bash script which runs commands in two terminal / ssh sessions

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant

I'm trying to automate setting up and configuring a vagrant process with a bash script.

The thing is, I need to to ssh into my vagrant machine twice, and I want both terminals to be visible on my screen whilst doing this.

The process is like so...

In terminal 1:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh myhost
wait
cd /my/directory/
... do some commands...
```

Then I want this terminal to persist / stay open, and a new tab to open where another vagrant session starts

```
wait
cd /my/other/directory
.... do some commands...
```

I've got the script working for the first vagrant/terminal session and stored in my /bin/ directory, but how do I add the second?

Answer (score 0):

How it looks exactly depends on the terminal emulator, but the basic pattern could be as follows:

First script (`script1.sh`)

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh myhost
wait
cd /my/directory/
xterm -e script2.sh &
... do some commands...
```

Second script (`script2.sh`)

```
wait
cd /my/other/directory
.... do some commands...
```

The trick is to open another terminal window from the first script (for `xterm` its `xterm -e`).

In case you are interested in a way that works indepedently of the terminal emulator, consider using `tmux` (terminal multiplexer).

Other general hint: It is generally not recommended to store locally-created scripts under `/bin`. A more common place would be `/usr/local/bin` or `$HOME/bin` (although `$HOME/bin` might need to be configured separately).